# Working with a form in Add mode

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

please bear with me while I try to explain my problem. I am opening a form in Add mode; the form is bound to a single table but contains a subform linked to another table - the 2 tables have a 1 to many relationship. I enter some data which triggers the autoref to populate on the main form, and create a linked record on the subform. I then click a button on the main form to open another form. Using vba on the OnClick event of this button, I save the record on the current form and create a new record in a different table. This table is the data source for the 2nd form, and I open the form filtered to the newly created record. I enter some data in this secondary form and then click a button which takes a calculated value and populates a field on the main form and then closes the second form. The problem is that when it returns to the main form it seems to have lost the original record, as if it's back in Add mode. However, if I enter data on the main form and then simply close it, I can re-open it (in Edit mode) and open the 2nd form and back again without any problem. Sorry for the long-winded explanation but hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been programming Access for almost 20 years, and I've never found a use for Add mode. In other words, it has always been more trouble than it is worth.

Since you are coding already, I would just use `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec` where needed to take you to a new record. Just make sure `AllowAdditions` is set to Yes in form properties.

Since this question is very general, it is hard to get any more specific than this. But if you do run into a specific problem that you can demonstrate in your code, update your question and I'll take a look.